# OAuth2 coonection to a server - android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in which when the user enters the email id and submit, I want to connect to the server using oAuth2 and store the mail id in the list. I have the url, access_token, client id, client secret and post header and body. But I'm not sure how to implement it. Any help is highly appreciated